# How to Lable the R usmap in quantile

Tags: r

I've generated an map with code:

```
plot_usmap(data = df, values = "ServicePerFFS", color = "red") + 
  scale_fill_continuous(name = "ServicePerFFS (2017)", type = "viridis", label = scales::comma) + 
  theme(legend.position = "right")
```

However, I want to change the label in quantile. I am interested in different ways of doing that.

```
 dput(head(df))
    structure(list(abbr = c("AK", "AL", "AR", "AZ", "CA", "CO"), 
    fips = c("02", "01", "05", "04", "06", "08"), full = c("Alaska", 
    "Alabama", "Arkansas", "Arizona", "California", "Colorado"
    ), pop_2015 = c(738432, 4858979, 2978204, 6828065, 39144818, 
    5456574), FFSpop = c(82927, 969116, 593592, 1155335, 5478663, 
    789379), Service = c(413, 7776, 7105, 8856, 64246, 8227), 
    ServicePerFFS = c(4980.28386412146, 8023.80726352676, 11969.5009366703, 
    7665.30919603405, 11726.5836573631, 10422.116625854)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please provide some of your date with `dput(head(df))`

Comment: I've added the data above

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't make my question clearer. I meant that I still want all the data shows in all the states, but I want the label on the right (0, 25%of ServicePerFFS, 50%of ServicePer FFS,  75%of ServicePerFFS, 100%of ServicePerFFS). Let me know if it make sense.

Comment: Ok, see updated post (it only shows data in a few states in my plot because I only have a fraction of your data)

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
df$ServicePerFFS <- percent_rank(df$ServicePerFFS)

plot_usmap(data = df, values = "ServicePerFFS", color = "red") + 
  scale_fill_continuous(name = "ServicePerFFS (2017)", type = "viridis", label = scales::comma) + 
  theme(legend.position = "right")
```

[image]

---

Edit:

```
plot_usmap(data = df, values = "ServicePerFFS", color = "red") + 
  scale_fill_continuous(name = "ServicePerFFS (2017)", type = "viridis", breaks = as.numeric(quantile(df$ServicePerFFS)),labels = paste(round(quantile(df$ServicePerFFS),2),names(quantile(df$ServicePerFFS)), "of ServicePer FFS")) + 
  theme(legend.position = "right")
```